# image carousel showing all images

Tags: jquery, html, css

for some flipping reason my image carousel is showing all the images at once. I don't know why but I think it has something to do with my css.

```
#full_image {
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute;
}

#full_image ul li img {
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 list-style: none outside none;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#full_image .full_close {
 background: url('icons/zoom-on.png') no-repeat;
 top: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 29px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 width: 29px;
 z-index: 999;
 right: 10px;
}

#full_image .next_big {
 background: url('icons/arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
 top: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 29px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 width: 29px;
 z-index: 999;
 right: 0px;
}
#full_image .prev_big {
 background: url('icons/arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
 top: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 29px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 width: 29px;
 z-index: 999;
 left: 0px;
 color: #222;
}

<div id="full_image"> 
    <ul><li><img src="'+img+'" /></a></li></ul> 
    <a href="#" class="full_close"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button next_big"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button prev_big"></a>
 </div>
```

How I'm loading up the images.

```
$.each(get_org_images, function (i, img) {
      if (i > 0){
          $('#full_image ul').append('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>');} });
```

Comment: So by this javascript you want to replace images, am I right?

Comment: the js does replace images because the image car. get used my different sets of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know what you mean with, "they show at once". What do you expect them to do? 
Maybe some more info. would help.

but, you could do some performance stuff like:

```
var parent = $('#full_image').find("ul");
$.each(get_org_images, function (i, img) {
      if (i > 0){
          parent.append('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>');} });
```

Dont have to select each time the parent in the each.
And `$('#full_image').find("ul")` is better selector then `$('#full_image ul')`

you can do simply that:

```
parent.append('<li><img style="display:none;" src="' + img + '"/></li>');} });
```

which .hide() would do.

Comment: That still does the same thing. The images are list vertically. can I do something like   $('#full_image ul').append('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>').hide()

Answer (score 1):

If your JavaScript is written to replace images, then you have to use *html* instead of *append* in your code. Then new image will replace the old one.

Try this:

```
$.each(get_org_images, function (i, img) {
      if (i > 0){
          $('#full_image ul').html('<li><img src="' + img + '"/></li>');} });
```